# Finding vertices to edit/correct on a character mesh (only seen in Object mode)

Tags: rigging, armature

I am trying to locate errant vertices on a character that I see in Object or Weight mode, but in Edit mode they appear to be in correct positions.

[image]

I have succeeded in guessing some vertices, but there must be a better way...

[image]

If I delete the armature modifier, I still have the same problem.

I include a light weight example, working around the evil "All uploaded files must be in the blend file format" via this [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz56z9smsxbhsle/rigged_vertex_problem.blend?dl=0)

Per @Nathan 's answer, I've been able to select the vertex to edit:

[image]

But am still confused how to then correct it's position in Edit Mode:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, there is a better way.  Switch to vertex mode in weight paint mode:

[image]

In vertex mode, you can select individual, deformed vertices easily.  You can then inspect vertices' properties in sidebar/item; you can also tab into edit and you'll still have the same vertices selected.  (And vice versa: you can use edit mode to take advantage of its superior selection tools for purposes of weight painting.)

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.   What do they say about leading a horse to water?  I'm following you in how to select the desired vertex, but am still confused on how to see the errant position in Edit Mode, and subsequently move it to the desired position.  I edited to add more to my above question (2 more images).

Comment: If they're errant in weight paint, but not in edit, their errancy is a function of their modifiers-- probably, an armature modifier.  You don't want to "fix" them in edit mode anyways.  You probably want to change their weights instead.  However, if you want, you can enable edit mode or cage mode display of the modifier(s) and see what moving the offending vertex in edit mode does to the modified mesh.

Comment: I took a look at your file, after reading you're having problems with cage display (not sure how I missed that before, focusing on the main question)-- but there's one mesh in there, which doesn't look like the mesh in your picture, and tabbing into edit mode doesn't change the deformation at all.  Posing it, the cage display works fine.  Might consider uploading a file that better demonstrates your problems?

Comment: Nathan thanks so much for your time.  I have updated the file with a mesh where Edit mode does not show the same vertex positions as Weight mode.

Comment: @james_t I see, the problem is not with your modifiers, but with your shapekeys.  You have a shapekey set to 1.0, but you're on the Basis shapekey.  When you tab into edit, it shows you Basis, without any shapekeys.  You should be selecting a shapekey from the list and editing it-- like DzCIndex3Dwn_90_R , which is probably what is responsible for what you don't like.

Comment: Voila, Nathan.  You are the master sleuth, more clevererer than Shirlock !